# Why does this backgorund Image not show up?(CSS/TAILWIND/REACT)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I really dont get why this does not work as exspected... Pictures should be self-explanatory. Not sure if you can see them, so the code is also there...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvOhQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDr8Q.png

```
.bg-rbg {
  background-image: url('/my-app/src/fuckingimage.png');
   }

.bg-cover {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

---

```
<div class="container flex flex-col pl-5 p-8 bg-rbg bg-cover bg-norepeat">
```

The image it self is not the problem, I tried it with more than one and even if I click on the image path I also get to the correct image...

Comment: as far i see, theres no problem with the css and html. it might be on tailwind. dont add new css in the tailwind css file. add them in the new css file.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the example given by the tailwind website:
Import your image with a style tag:

```
<div class="bg-scroll ..." style="background-image: url(...)"></div>
```

Comment: i already tried that one...

Comment: THe complicated thing about that is, that it have to work out with React and Tailwind...

Comment: I don't have any experience with react and tailwind..
I found this video by someone whom I watch a lot so maybe he can help you out
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywLgqJjLUm4